# Question about html radio input deselection

Tags: html

if I use below code, why I cannot deselect the radio items? and can I give the 2 items 2 different "name" in the input sections? (e.g. name="language1" and name="language2")? Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="radio" name="language1" id="language1" value="'a'" class="css-checkbox" checked="" >
<label for="language1">a</label>
  <input type="radio" name="language2" id="language2" value="'b'" class="css-radio" checked="">
<label for="language2">b</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You used different values for `name` attribute, these two radio buttons will be considered different. So if You want to select only either of the two(consider both radio button as single option), You have two use same value for `name` attribute.

Regarding the selection, Since only one **radio** button available under each group( *language1* and *language2*) and you already mentioned checked attribute, it will be selected and you can not remove the selection.

If you want to select either of the option, then change your code as follows(By using same value foe `name` attribute):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="radio" name="language1" id="language1" value="'a'" class="css-checkbox" checked="" >
<label for="language1">a</label>
  <input type="radio" name="language1" id="language2" value="'b'" class="css-radio" >
<label for="language2">b</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```